# Pairwise not being imported with itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, pairwise

I'm on python 3.8.2 and I've tried the following code

```
from itertools import pairwise
```

However, it returns

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools' (unknown location)
```

I tried other variants of the same thing like `import itertools` `itertools.pairwise`, but it still gave me errors.

I figured it could be a spelling mistake so I tried

```
from itertools import *

print(dir())
```

But it wasn't there

`['__builtins__', '__file__', '__name__', '__warningregistry__', 'accumulate', 'chain', 'combinations', 'combinations_with_replacement', 'compress', 'count', 'cycle', 'dropwhile', 'filterfalse', 'groupby', 'islice', 'permutations', 'product', 'repeat', 'starmap', 'takewhile', 'tee', 'zip_longest']`

I even tried it on different devices and an online interpreter. [image: screenshot of the online interpreter because this sounds crazy]

Comment: Check your *Python* version.  It comes in Py 3.10+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *pairwise* only comes with Python 3.10+. In previsous version, it is listed under **Itertools Recipes** section.

That's why you cannot find it.  Try to upgrade to latest version always.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html  <- official doc.